# How to join column with several hits with Awk

Tags: awk

I have a tabulate file like this, joj001.txt:

```
C00299  map01
C00125  map65
C00299  map13
```

and a csv file , dora.csv:

```
V1    V2       V3
D12   C00299   4
E10   C01832   5
```

I want to add a column (or generate a new csv file) with all the hit when the column V2 contain the keys, like this :

```
V1    V2        V3    V4
D12   C00299    4    map01,map13
E10   C01835    5
```

But so far, I've got this :

```
$ awk -F'\t' -vOFS="\t" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next}{print $0,a[$2]}' joj001.txt mia.csv

V1    V2        V3    V4
D12   C00299    4    map13
E10   C01835    5
```

How to have all the occurence, separate by a comma?

Thanks you

Comment: Change `a[$1]=$2` to `a[$1]=a[$1](a[$1]!=""?",":"")$2`.

Comment: Thank you it seems to work !

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your CSV file does not contain commas, so I assume it is tab separated (TSV)?

Answer (score 0):

Your script overwrites the value in `a[$1]` instead of appending to it.

There are many ways to append instead. For example:

```
if ( a[$1] ) a[$1] = a[$1] "," $2; else a[$1] = $2

a[$1] = a[$1] ( a[$1] ? "," : "" ) $2

a[$] = ( a[$1] ? a[$1] "," : "" ) $2

a[$1] = a[$1] ? a[$1] "," $2 : $2


a[$1] = a[$1] "," $2;
# then once at the end:
sub(/^,/,"",a[$1])
```

You also need to insert the new column header.

So:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '
    FNR==NR { a[$1] = a[$1] ? a[$1] "," $2 : $2; next }
    FNR==1 { print $0, "V4"; next }
    { print $0, a[$2] }
' joj001.txt mia.csv
```